# why can uploaded files not be open using download URL in Google's firebase storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase for my iOS application, for one feature in my app, I have to upload attachments on firebase server and later it will be retrieved in-app for preview (e.g. Question attachments)

I can able to upload the file successfully, also it shows on firebase with the proper size, content type etc but it does not generate preview or not opening using download URL (Please see attached screenshot)

what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you click the download URL in firebase console, it copies the url to clipboard, you need to paste it in browser to open it.

If you are doing that but it is still not opening, check security rules and make sure that user id you used to login has read access to the file.

Comment: it gives below error on browser when we paste download url and try to open it,
The image “https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/../o/attachments%2Fdoc-xxxxxxx?alt=media&token=6c9380ea-xxxxxxxx” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: Try with different file and also check security rules.